# Is there a way to know which permissions a Flutter package will require my app to request?

Tags: flutter, permissions, dependencies

I was notified by the iOS app store that my app references an API that I am not explicitly making use of.  I believe it comes from an upgrade of the flutter_google_maps package, but how would I know? I realize that just because I'm not making use of the permission doesn't mean that Apple won't catch that in static analysis.

Is there a way to know what permissions my app is going to have to require if I pull in a package?  Perhaps this is something pub.dev could show?